# What's the difference between the "line" and "path" series types in Plots.jl?

Tags: plot, julia, plots.jl

The plots generated using the options `seriestype = :line` and `seriestype = :path` look completely identical to me.

Comment: One's sorted in `x` and the other isn't. I forget which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:line` is sorted in `x`, and `:path` takes your input and does not do any sorting.